# How can I access content of a website client side?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I've set up my own whatsmyip type site that returns a simple string of the callers external IP.

But I can't figure out how to get the queried text into an asp control for use.

I can load it up in an iframe and see it on the page, but accessing it and using it is blocked for built in security reasons.

I can get it working server side with ~WebClient.DownloadString("Whatsmyip.com").
But I need the client's IP, not the web servers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use whatsmyip.com? You can also get a users ip address through `HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress`.

Comment: If I always want to get the users external IP, I think so. Does that always return the clients external IP? It's been giving me my local ip when tested locally.

Comment: .. which makes sense, since when testing locally you are the user. And yes, it will always return the requestors IP address.

Comment: Unless you are deploying this within a corporation's network, you should always get the ip address that the user is connecting to the server from. In your case, as Lester has said, you are connecting locally, so you're getting your local ip address, if you were to publish it to an external web server, it would give you your external ip that is connecting to that server

Comment: I've tried HTTP_X_COMING_FROM,HTTP_X_FORWARDED,HTTP_VIA,HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR,HTTP_FORWARDED,HTTP_FROM,HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION,CLIENT_IP,FORWARDED, REMOTE_ADDR and Request.UserHostAddress. None of which contains my clients IP after I host the site. The site is hosted behind a load balancer.

Comment: It must be blocked by the load balancer since at least one of those options you listed should work. You'll have to ask at Server Fault.